# Installable trigger created using "ScriptApp.newTrigger" has to be re-saved before it will run

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-installable-triggers

I have an Expenses sheet that I copy to the Google Drive folder for each of my relevant users. Each copy of the sheet needs an installable trigger that calls a function to insert additional rows when the last row of data gets edited. These are triggered using the onEdit event. The installable triggers work fine when created manually (via "`Edit Current Project's triggers`").

To simplify the process of setting up new users, I have scripted the creation of my trigger. Although the script creates the trigger and it appears exactly the same as the manually created one, it only works if I manually open up the trigger, re-select the function to trigger and re-save it.

I can confirm I am the owner when running the creation script.

The behaviour I'm seeing suggests to me that there is something incorrect with the function name in my script however it all looks fine to me. I'd really appreciate some help with this....

```
function createInsertRowsTrigger(){
  Logger.log('Id='+ss.getId());
createInstallableTrigger("onEditOfLastRow",ss.getId());
}

function createInstallableTrigger(funcName,ssId) {
      if(!isTrigger(funcName)) {
        ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcName).forSpreadsheet(ssId).onEdit().create();
      }
    }

function isTrigger(funcName){
       Logger.log('In isTrigger');
   var r=false;
   if(funcName){
     Logger.log('Function found');
     var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
     for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
       if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
         r=true;
         Logger.log('trigger already exists');
         break;
       }
     }
   }
   return r;
 }
```

The full code is here....

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('SCLGA Expenses Menu')
      .addItem('Approve Expenses', 'ApproveExpenses')  
      .addToUi();

  resetValidationRules();
 }

//===========================================================================================
// global 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
//===========================================================================================

function onEditofLastRow(e) {
  var value = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(3, 6).getValue();// row number of the last but one row
  editedCol =e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getColumn();
  editedRow =e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();

  // if the last cell in the last row is edited...create some more rows...
  if(editedCol==7 && editedRow==  value-1){
       showAlert('Looks like you need some more rows... ');
       insertRows();
  }
}




function createInsertRowsTrigger(){
  Logger.log('Id='+ss.getId());
createInstallableTrigger("onEditOfLastRow",ss.getId());
}


function createInstallableTrigger(funcName,ssId) {
      if(!isTrigger(funcName)) {
        ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcName).forSpreadsheet(ssId).onEdit().create();
      }
    }

function isTrigger(funcName){
       Logger.log('In isTrigger');
   var r=false;
   if(funcName){
     Logger.log('Function found');
     var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
     for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
       if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
         r=true;
         Logger.log('trigger already exists');
         break;
       }
     }
   }
   return r;
 }
function showAlert(msg) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var result = ui.alert(msg);
}

function insertRows() {
    // this function inserts some new rows and copies relevant formulas and formats


    // this value tells us  where the next data section starts
    var value = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(3, 6).getValue();
    var rowsToAdd = 5;
    var firstRow = value-rowsToAdd;
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
    var range = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, rowsToAdd, lCol);


    // copy formulas 
    var formulaRange1 = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, rowsToAdd, 1);
    var formulaRange2 = sh.getRange(firstRow, 8, rowsToAdd, lCol-8);
    var formulas1 = formulaRange1.getFormulasR1C1();
    var formulas2 = formulaRange2.getFormulasR1C1();

    // insert rows
    sh.insertRowsAfter(firstRow+rowsToAdd-1, rowsToAdd);

    // define new range
    newRange1 = sh.getRange(firstRow+rowsToAdd, 1, rowsToAdd, 1);
    newRange2 = sh.getRange(firstRow+rowsToAdd, 8, rowsToAdd, lCol-8);

    // set formulas
    newRange1.setFormulasR1C1(formulas1);
    newRange2.setFormulasR1C1(formulas2);

    // copy formatting for range 2 
    range.copyFormatToRange(sh, 1, lCol-8, firstRow+rowsToAdd, firstRow+rowsToAdd+rowsToAdd-1);


    resetValidationRules();
    resetTransactionUploadFormulas();
}

function resetTransactionUploadFormulas(){
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Transactions to load');
  sourceFormulas = sheet.getRange(2,1,1,12).getFormulasR1C1();
  for (i=3; i<=250; i++)
      newRange=sheet.getRange(i,1,1,12).setFormulasR1C1(sourceFormulas);  

}



function resetValidationRules(){
    var value = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(3, 6).getValue();
    var firstRow = 5; 
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
    var range = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 245, lCol);

  // Apply validation rules to all rows
    for(i = 1; i <= 250; i++){
        currentRowNumber = 4+i;
        var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('F'+currentRowNumber);
        var eventRange = sh.getRange("L"+currentRowNumber+":BB"+currentRowNumber)
        var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(eventRange).build();
        if (value != currentRowNumber && value+1 != currentRowNumber)
          cell.setDataValidation(rule);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using the `Sheet.appendRow` function? `onEdit(e)` can only handle 2 edits at a time and will simply ignore the rest if the user "edits" too quickly. Why not just use `importrange`?

Comment: Hi @CodeCamper, I'm not using the appendRow function as my expense sheet has some different sections and I'm only inserting rows into the first section. Hence inserting rather than appending.

Comment: ...and to clarify, I am using the onEdit event and this is triggering my own function rather than the simple onEdit() function. The problem I am finding is that my installable triggers don't work unless I re-open them, re-select my function to trigger and re-save....

Comment: Installable Triggers are very dangerous because they run under the gmail account you install them, usually you need to manually install them because you are effectively authorizing each sheet to potentially delete all your emails etc. So maybe it has to do with the required authorization to install a trigger, not sure. You can use appendRow function on specific sheets I'm not sure why you need to add rows, but I see you edited your question and wanted a new blank row anytime the user types in the last row, you can just appendRow when typing in the last row...